# Is this an example of restrictive appositive? Should there be no commas?

Tags: commas, appositives

I'm having doubts about the placement of commas in this sentence:

> Sarah found herself negotiating with producer Rob for his next film, *The Tower*.

If I want to convey that Rob has made multiple films in his career, should I put commas before *The Tower* or should I not put in any commas to convey that *The Tower* is one of his many next films?

Should the sentence be this:

> Sarah found herself negotiating with producer Rob for his next film *The Tower*.

Comment: Semantically there can only be one next film, so it would make no sense to restrict the meaning with an integrated appositive. Thus, it can only be a supplementary (non-restrictive) appositive - the kind with a comma.

Comment: So a comma would signal that this was the only next movie at the specified time. Okay, thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, because presumably Rob can only make one film at a time.